# Radio Buttons in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, testing, selenium-webdriver

I have a form and cannot figure out how to automate the selection of a radio button.

The ID for the one which I need to click is "c100"

html code for the option I need to click:

```
<input id="cl00" type="radio" name="MYN" value="cl00">
```

c# code as follows:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("//input[@value='c100']")).Click();
```

Ive also tried:

```
 IWebElement radio = driver.FindElement(By.Id("c100"));
 radio.Click();
```

I have tried all the different ways including javascript. Can someone plase tell me what I am doing wrong?!

Comment: Check whether the element is in different frame, if it is in different frame then switch to that frame and try to click

Comment: Well what errors are you getting? Key information missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
By.Id("//input[@value='c100']")
```

To:

```
By.Xpath("//input[@value='c100']")
```

Xpaths are useful for finding elements without displayed text or hidden elements.

Use http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/ for future reference.

Hope it helps!